# Program to Copy a Text File to another Location using Keyboard input

Tags: java, io, undefined-symbol

I am writing a program to copy a text file to another file location from keyboard input and am having trouble. The file names are in the correct places when entered from the keyboard, but the content is not there. I have gotten one line to copy correctly into the next file.  At the moment, I am receiving a cannot find symbol error on line 41.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class lity
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Directory of file to be copied");
      String dir = keyboard.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Name of file to be copied");
      String file = keyboard.nextLine();
      File copied = new File(dir, file);

      BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new FileReader(copied));
      String str;

      while((str = in.readLine())!=null)
      {
       char[] n;
       n = str.toCharArray();
      }
      in.close();



      System.out.println("Path of pasted file");
      String pdir = keyboard.nextLine();
      File newdir = new File(pdir);  

      if(!newdir.exists())
      {
       newdir.mkdir();
      }

      System.out.println("pasted file name");
      String pfile = keyboard.nextLine();
      File myfile = new File(newdir, pfile);

      FileWriter stream = new FileWriter(myfile);

      stream.write(n);
      stream.close();
      }

     }
```

new code

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class CopyFile
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
      String s = " ";
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);


      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("enter directory path of the file to be pasted:");
      String dirName = keyboard.next();
      System.out.println("enter file name of the file to be copied");
      String fileName = keyboard.next();
      try
      {
       File input = new File(dirName, fileName);



       Scanner ind = new Scanner(input);  
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input));
       String str;

       try
       {
        while(ind.hasNextLine())
        {
         str = in.readLine(); 
         sb.append(str+"\n");
        }
        in.close();
        ind.close();
       }

       catch(IOException e)
       {
        System.out.println("IOException");
       }

       System.out.println("path of file to be pasted");
       String dir = keyboard.next();
       File myDir = new File(dir);

       if(!myDir.exists())
       {
        myDir.mkdir();
       }   


       System.out.println("enter name of the file to be pasted");
       String mfile;
       mfile = keyboard.next();
       try
       {
        File myFile = new File(myDir, mfile);

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));

        String nstr;
        nstr = sb.toString();
    char[] n = nstr.toCharArray();
        for(int d = 0;d < n.length; d++)
    {
     pw.write(n[d]);
    }
        pw.close();
       }
      catch(IOException e)
      {
       System.out.println(e);
      }
     }
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
       {
        System.out.println(e);
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: which line is line 41?

Comment: Yep, I figured that as I was reading through your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the `n` variable locally inside of your loop, and then trying to use it elsewhere. To get the code to compile you would need to declare it in the main method or in the class.

Regardless, even if the code compiled, it would still fail since you're re-creating the char array with each loop where you read in from the file. Consider either using a StringBuilder to get all the Strings, either that or reading and writing at the same time in one loop.

Something like (in pseudo-code):

```
create StringBuilder
Open file to read in a Scanner or BufferedReader
Loop through text of file
  append each String from file into the StringBuilder
  You probably want to append "\n" with each line added
end loop
close the Scanner or BufferedReader

Open file to write and create a PrintWriter with it
write out StringBuilder's String using toString() into the file using PrintWriter
close the PrintWriter.
```

Comment: There is still nothing written in the file. What I have written is above.

Comment: @user3277602: your latest code does in fact work, except you probably need to append the `"\n"` to each line as I recommend above. Also there's no need to pass a space into the StringBuilder's constructor.

Comment: Done. formatting is odd at the bottom, but you get the idea.

Comment: @user3277602: don't use **both** a Scanner and a BufferedReader at the same time -- that makes no sense. It's one or the other.